# DynamoDB Single Table many to many to many

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a data relationship of many Users to many Roles to many Permissions. The Users to Roles many to many relationship is handled in a single table using different indexes to represent which side of the many to many relationship you are on. I am trying to figure out how to get the permissions represented. Here is what I want to end up with using just one call to DynamoDB.

```
{
  username: 'User Name',
  roles: [
    {
      roelName: 'Role Name',
      permissions: [{ permissionName: 'Permission Name' }],
    },
  ],
}
```

I can make the same relationship between roles and permissions using the single table principle but how do I link the user all the way to the permissions.

Another option would be to keep the permissions denormalized and living with each role. I am not too found of this because I would have to update every role linked to a user when the roles permissions changed.

So how do you represent this relationship in DynamoDB and still keep the calls down to one ?

Answer (score 1):

Try modelling as an adjacency list

> When different entities of an application have a many-to-many relationship between them, the relationship can be modeled as an adjacency list. In this pattern, all top-level entities (synonymous to nodes in the graph model) are represented using the partition key. Any relationships with other entities (edges in a graph) are represented as an item within the partition by setting the value of the sort key to the target entity ID (target node).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html

Comment: Yes, this is what I am currently doing. I am trying to figure out how to get the permissions when I have a user. I can keep the permissions on the role but would have to update the permissions on every User-Role combination when the permissions changed on the role.